# Differences in data types from two approaches

Tags: powershell, types

If I declare a data type like this:

```powershell
Add-Type -TypeDefinition "public class MyTest {}"
```

and then create an object and get its data type, I get `MyTest`, as I would expect:

```powershell
(new-object MyTest).GetType().Name
```

but if I refer to the type directly...

```powershell
[MyTest].GetType().Name
```

I get `RuntimeType`.  can anyone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `Add-Type` cmdlet in particular; it applies to all PowerShell types:

```powershell
PS > (1).GetType().Name
Int32
PS > [int].GetType().Name
RuntimeType
```

Things like `(new-object MyTest)` and `1` are instances of specific types.  Calling `.GetType()` on them is returning the type of those instances.

Things like `[MyTest]` and `[int]` however are instances of the `RuntimeType` class, which represents all PowerShell runtime types (things in `[...]`).  That is why `[MyTest].GetType().Name` is returning `RuntimeType`.  You are basically getting the type of the `MyTest` class itself, not its instances.

Below is a visual breakdown:

```powershell
new-object MyTest  # MyTest instance
[MyTest]           # RuntimeType instance
1                  # Integer instance
[int]              # RuntimeType instance
```

Comment: oh... I get it.  so [int] is the same as (1).GetType()